# Unable to push files to remote github repository using visual studio IDE

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am trying to push some files to my remote github repository using Visual Studio IDE. I added the files and committed but get the following error:

```
A custom tool 'MSDataSetGenerator' is associated with file 
'MyDBDataSet.xsd', but the output of the custom tool was not found in 
the project. You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the 
file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.
```

Does anybody knows the answer for this problem.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Please show us the exact commands that you tried with the output. Somehow the error seems not related to pushing to a remote Git repository. Do you have a *pre-push* hook set?

Comment: Sir I did not try any code/command. I just try it using the visual studio. Instead of using git terminal, from visual studio also can push a commit. So, I tried that way. I am not familiar with git terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to github or git. It looks like some Visual Studio validation error. Try to do what it asks

Solution Explorer

1. Right Click on 'MyDBDataSet.xsd'
2. Run Custom Tool

Or do cleanup -> rebuild

1. Right Click on the Project Name > Clean
2. Right Click on the Project Name > Rebuild